# TypeScript types with JSX.Element on react will not accept .map()and gives error TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a calendar out of table elements and I am using TypeScript. This is my first time using TypeScript and I am puzzled as to why my type is not accepted. As you will see below in the code I use JSX elements as  and push them according to rows of 7.

```
const blankCells: JSX.Element[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth(); i++) {
        blankCells.push(
            <td role="presentation">None</td>
        );
    }

    const datesInMonth: JSX.Element[] = [];
    for (let day = 1; day <= daysOfMonth; day++) {
        datesInMonth.push(
            <td key={day} role="presentation">
                <button>{day}</button>
            </td>
        );
    }

    const totalDateElementsOfCalendar:JSX.Element[] = [...blankCells, ...datesInMonth];
    const calendarRows: (JSX.Element | JSX.Element[])[] = []; 
    let calendarSlot: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] = [];

    totalDateElementsOfCalendar.forEach((dateElement, i) => {
        if (i % 7 !== 0) {
            calendarSlot.push(dateElement); 
        } else {
            calendarRows.push(calendarSlot); 
            calendarSlot = []; 
            calendarSlot.push(dateElement); 
        }
        if (i === totalDateElementsOfCalendar.length - 1) { 
            calendarRows.push(calendarSlot);
        }
    });
```

In line

```
if (i % 7 !== 0) {
            calendarSlot.push(dateElement);
```

TypeScript gives me an error "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Element | Element[]'.
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Element'. (ts2339)" This error is not present in the else statement right below it. I am puzzled as to what I am defining wrong. Would be great full for an explanation as to why this is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't done anything that TypeScript can see that tells it that the variable is an `Element[]`, not just an `Element`. Your type says it could be either, but only the array type has `push`.

You don't seem to need the first part of your type, just declare it as `Element[]`:

```typescript
let calendarSlot: JSX.Element[] = [];
```

Looking at the code, maybe you intended it to be an array that could contain `Element` or `Element[]` values? If so, you need `()`:

```typescript
let calendarSlot: (JSX.Element | JSX.Element[])[] = [];
```

or you could use `Array<T>`:

```typescript
let calendarSlot: Array<JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]> = [];
```